# Flooding function, displaying time until can post again

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem i cant figure out. I have a function to prohibit users from posting more than once every 30 sec, it works, but I want to display time left.

The function looks like this:

```
function isFlooding($userid) 
{

$time = time() - 30;

$recentPost = $db->prepare('SELECT MAX(posted) FROM comments WHERE poster = ?');
$recentPost->execute(array($userid));

return ($recentPost->fetchColumn() > $time) ? true : false;
}
```

Could I somehow return the time left instead of true?

I've tried

```
$waitTime = 30 - (time() - $recentPost->fetchColumn());
$waitTime = floor($waitTime / 60);


return ($recentPost->fetchColumn() > $time) ? $waitTime : false;
```

but it doesnt return anything, $waitTime is always empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you dividing it by 60?

Function `time()` returns time in seconds, and you then divide it by 60 - so as there isn't any full minute, it returns 0 just because it's being rounded down.

So the proper code should probably be just this line

`$waitTime = 30 - (time() - $recentPost->fetchColumn());`